# How to make ticks longer?

Tags: ticks

Good time of day. I want to make ticks longer but cannot.                                                     Here is the code

```
Needs["MaTeX`"]
ticks[min_, max_] := 
 Table[If[EvenQ[i], {i, i, .06, Red}, {i, i, .02, Blue}], {i, 
   Ceiling[min], Floor[max], 1}]
Plot[{Bz}, {Bz, 20, 25}, Frame -> True, BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 16}, Exclusions -> None, Ticks -> ticks, 
PlotLegends -> Placed[LineLegend[
    MaTeX[#, Magnification -> 20/12] & @{"\\textrm{Re}\\Sigma=0", 
      "\\textrm{Re}\\Sigma\\neq 0", "\\textrm{zero-width LL curve A}",
 "\\textrm{zero-width LL curve B}"}, 
    LegendLayout -> {"Row", 1}, LegendFunction -> Framed], {Center, 
    Top}], FrameLabel -> {MaTeX["2\\mu_B B_z,\\ K", 
    Magnification -> 30/12], 
   MaTeX["M /(\\nu_{3D}\\mu_B)", Magnification -> 30/12]}, 
 PlotStyle -> {{Thickness[0.002], Black, 
 Dashing[Large]}, {Thickness[0.004], Green}, {Thickness[0.002], 
 Blue, Dashing[{0.0005, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02}]}, {Thickness[0.004], 
 Yellow, Dashing[{0.0005, 0.04, 0.01, 0.05, 0.03, 0.03}]}}, 
 PerformanceGoal -> {"Speed"}, PlotPoints -> 30000, MaxRecursion -> 0,
 PlotRange -> {Full, {-320, 320}}, 
 TicksStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 16], ImageSize -> 1000, 
 AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio]
```

Comment: https://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Demos/5599/CustomTicksGuide.pdf

Comment: Not a direct answer (for that I do recommend CustomTicks), but I think the best way to handle this is to not make the plot unnecessarily large. You made it 1000 points wide, which is 35 centimetres. It would not even fit on an A4 paper when printed. Check the "Preparing Figures to Size" tutorial in the MaTeX documentation—you might find some good tips there.

Comment: If `Frame -> True`, use `FrameTicks` instead of `Ticks`.